# Can we say "to drink out" (similar to "eat out") to mean to drink away from home?

Tags: word-usage

We all know that *to eat out* means “to eat away from home, esp in a restaurant” per the [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eat+out).

However, I have not heard anyone say *to drink out*. The Internet doesn’t have any information about it.

Does

> *to drink out*: to drink away from home, esp. in coffee shop or pub, etc.

make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a term is not used.

To convey the meaning that you describe, people say: *let's go out for a drink.*

Consequently, simply saying *let's go out* has come to mean the same thing, and so *go out* is equivalent to *eat out*.

My answer is a British English perspective.

Comment: "let's go out for a drink" is a long expression, why not "to drink out". Can we invent the term "to drink out". I think people can understand what I mean

Comment: As my answer stated, you can simply say *let's go out* and, provided the context is appropriate, you will be understood. That's short enough, surely?

Comment: "go out": "leave one's home to go to an entertainment or social event, typically in the evening". It does not say to drink or something

Comment: An entertainment or social event = a drinking occasion. Especially when it occurs in the evening. To go out for a drink is really a social event, rather than a gastronomic one. Besides, despite what it may say in a dictionary, I can assure you that if you were to say *go out* in the evening anywhere in the English-speaking world, it would be understood as *go out for a drink*.

Comment: As far as drinks are concerned, the "out" is optional.  It may be because when you "go out" to dinner, or "go out" for ice-cream, you have a destination in mind. You can "go out for drinks", but it is very common to "go for a drink", or "go drinking" because you don't know (or care) where you'll end up. (US)

Comment: A Google search for "drinking out" -"drinking out of" -"drinking out the" -"drinking out them" returns a substantial number of relevant results. I'd not bat an eyelid at 'eating and drinking out', but I'd not be too happy with 'drinking out' on its own (cf 'He spends his time wining' vs 'He spends his time wining and dining'), and find 'We'll drink out' unacceptable.

Comment: The same is true for AmE here, Charon.

Answer (score 1):

It is not common idiom to say for instance, "Let's drink out tonight".

You might say "Let's [get/go] out for a drink", as someone already posted above.

You might also say "Let's get a **drink out** at the beach".

But "drink out" as a phrase/action in its own right is not idiomatic (yet).

Answer (score 0):

We all know English language just like every language is living. If the phrase is not yet recognized in English Language but is very convenient, I guess it is high time we used it even more often. By that it will surely get the recognition it needs.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of characterizing some cases of eating as eating *out* is to mark them as departures from the default: eating at home. When someone says ‘Let’s eat out tonight’, that conveys something like ‘Let’s eat out tonight, instead of at home, as we usually do’. Saying of someone ‘He eats out frequently’, implies that he is different from average people, who eat most of their meals at home. Trying to transpose this to drinking would produce awkward results, because one’s home is not generally regarded as the default location for drinking (i.e. drinking alcoholic beverages, separately from a meal), in the way in which it is regarded as the default location for eating. That’s why, it does not normally occur to people to say ‘drink out’, and any attempt to introduce such a phrase could not make it analogous to ‘eat out’ (under the existing social conventions).

Answer (score 0):

These expressions were fairly common in London back in the 1980s, they all mean to enjoy a late evening in the company of friends. England being England, this involves visiting pubs or late night clubs and drinking a fair bit of alcohol.

> 1. I'm having a **night out** with the girls/boys (*[Collin's Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/night-out))*
> 2. We're **having a girls**'/boys' **night out**
> 3. We're having a **night out on the tiles** ([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on_the_tiles))